# html2canvas and Angular4 how to modify options

Tags: angular, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to create a download function for my Angular application. 
I have managed to get this working, but I am having an issue described here:

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/722

The images are from an external source, so are not being saved as part of the render. Apparently, you can set the boolean **allowTaint** and it will save the external images too, but as I am new to both Angular and html2canvas, I have no idea how to do this.
My code is as follows:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { ResultsService } from '../shared/results.service';
import { IResult } from '../shared/models/result.model';
import { IGroup } from '../shared/models/group.model';

import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import * as html2canvas from "html2canvas";

@Component({
  templateUrl: './results.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./results.component.scss']
})
export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  result: IResult;
  groups: IGroup[];
  private sub: any;

  constructor(
    private _resultsService: ResultsService,
    private _route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = +params['id'];
    });
    this._resultsService.get(this.id).subscribe(result => {
      this.result = result
      this.groups = JSON.parse(result.data);
    });
  }

  download() {
    html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
      var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      var doc = new jsPDF();
      doc.addImage(img,'JPEG',0,0);
      doc.save('test.pdf');
    });
  }
}
```

Where in that code can I set the **allowTaint** option?

Comment: There is nothing related to `html2canvas` in your code... Except the `import * as html2canvas from "html2canvas";`

Comment: Yeah I know, apparently that is needed, but does that mean I can just set the option on that variable? like `html2canvas.allowTaint = true` before adding the html?

Comment: You don't use that library.

Comment: so what is the import actually doing then?

Comment: Nothing, the import allows you to use it, but you don't.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. I will try to play around and see if I can find a solution

Comment: Ok, I have edited my question now and added the **html2canvas** in there.

Comment: `html2canvas(document.body,{allowTaint:true})` https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there are two ways of doing this.
You can use the above method and just add the options as a constructor parameter like this:

```
html2canvas(document.body, { allowTaint: true }).then(function(canvas) {
  var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  var doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.addImage(img,'JPEG',0,0);
  doc.save('test.pdf');
});
```

Or, as **jsPdf** already uses **html2canvas** you can just do this:

```
let pdf = new jsPDF();
pdf.addHTML(document.body, 0, 0, { allowTaint: true }, () => {
  pdf.save("test.pdf");
});
```